# Amplify federated buttons not showing up

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I installed the `@aws-amplify/ui-angular` packages.

Google sign in button are not showing up though.
I have the following in my `app.component.ts` file

```
<amplify-federated-buttons>
  <amplify-google-button></amplify-google-button>
</amplify-federated-buttons>
```

It also does not work if I use it as follows:

```
<amplify-google-button></amplify-google-button>
```

However, the following does show a login form.
But it only supports manual account creation. (no social logins)

```
<amplify-authenticator>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

There are no error messages in the console log.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that something was wrong with the `aws-exports.js` file.
This file is generated when you run the `amplify init` command from the terminal.

Simply running `amplify init` regenerated the file and resolved the problem.

Apparently, this is enough:

```
<amplify-google-button clientId="..."></amplify-google-button>
```

It results in:

[image: Google login button]