# AWS Cognito UI configured using Amplify in quasar/Vue3 doesn't show Facebook login button

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I'm using amplify to add auth UIs for AWS Cognito to my quasar/Vue3 website.

I used `amplify import auth` since I already have Cognito userpool configured sepratly.

Here is my sample App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="q-app">
    <div>
      <div v-if="authState !== 'signedin'">You are signed out.</div>
      <amplify-authenticator :federated="federatedIds">
        <div v-if="authState === 'signedin' && user">
          <div>Hello, {{user.username}}</div>
        </div>
        <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
      </amplify-authenticator>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { onAuthUIStateChange } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  created() {
    this.unsubscribeAuth = onAuthUIStateChange((authState, authData) => {
      this.authState = authState;
      this.user = authData;
    })
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user: undefined,
      authState: undefined,
      unsubscribeAuth: undefined,
      federatedConfig: { provider: "Facebook" },
      federatedIds: {
        facebookAppId: "*******"
      }
    }
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeAuth();
  }
})
</script>
```

Here is my boot file:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from '../aws-exports';
import {
  applyPolyfills,
  defineCustomElements,
} from '@aws-amplify/ui-components/loader';

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
  defineCustomElements(window);
});
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

I have spent hours looking for a solution, here are a few links

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-amplify/ui-components#vue
- https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3818
- [Amplify federated buttons not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818865/amplify-federated-buttons-not-showing-up)

Comment: How did you get Amplify to work with Quasar 2? I get many import errors once I add my boot file.

Comment: Did you get Amplify Cognito to work with Quasar? All I need is Cognito and there is also javascript sdk for it [https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone faces similar issue, you need to add `.prop` for amplify's properties:

`<amplify-authenticator :federated="federatedIds">` has to change to `<amplify-authenticator :federated.prop="federatedIds">`

I had to do the same thing for

```
<amplify-sign-up slot="sign-up" username-alias="email" :form-fields.prop="formFields">
</amplify-sign-up>
```

Reference: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5298#issuecomment-621124576